# Can I make an options menu the root of the stack?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

In MainActivity I've implemented the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method and I'm calling `openOptionsMenu()` from `onCreate`. This all works as expected.

The only issue is that the user can swipe down to close the menu which leaves them on an empty card. Swiping again shows the clock and "ok, glass".

Can I make it so that the open menu is the only thing in the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this behavior if you override `onOptionsMenuClosed` in your activity and call `finish()`. Note that `onOptionsMenuClosed` gets called both when the menu is canceled **and** when an item is selected though, so if you want to do something else when a menu item is selected, you'll need to keep track of that fact in `onOptionsItemSelected` and check it inside `onOptionsMenuClosed`.